# best way to check variable to be a number

Tags: php, performance, numbers

I have a php script that gets a number from administrator and changes associated user. it was fine until I realized `is_numeric` and `intval` functions have a funny behavior. here's the code I used:

```
if( ((empty($_GET["uid"]))  || (!isset($_GET["uid"])))){
    $id=0;
}else{
    if(is_numeric($_GET["uid"])){
        $id=intval($_GET["uid"]);
        if($id<0){
            $id=0;
        }
    }else{
        $id=0;
    }
}
```

But if I send `12er3` as input to script, `$id` will be `12`. Obviously it's not what I want. I found few ways to check input to ensure it consists of numbers( and only numbers):
1:

```
$id=(filter_var($_GET['uid'],FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)?(intval($_GET['uid'])<0?0:intval($_GET['uid'])):0);
```

2: 
[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901708/check-if-variable-has-a-number-php)

3:

```
preg_match("/^\d+$/",$_GET["uid"])
```

my question is which one is better way to use?

******
**Note:  $id should be a non-negative and integer number.**

**I have left it non-answered because no one answered my question: I was searching for best way NOT a way!**

Comment: @safarov  that's my question. I want to know `$id` would be a number only if given input is number. I don't want more surprises :-(

Comment: what part of your input represents the id ? I mean, which part do you want to extract from 12er3? 12? 123? 3?

Comment: it should be `0`  because it contains non-numeric characters:-(

Comment: I see. A comparison will help:

    if (intval($_GET["uid"]) == $_GET["uid"]) {
    // it only contains numbers
    }

Comment: is_numeric, niether intval doesn't have funny behavior, you have just misread Manual

Answer (score 2):

Use function [`ctype_digit`](http://php.net/ctype_digit) to check it.

Comment: using the function will be obviously better

Comment: it fails if input is `12er3` :-(  result should be **0**  not **12**

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php   -> Checks if all of the characters in the provided string, text, are numerical.Returns TRUE if every character in the string text is a decimal digit, FALSE otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's [is_numeric()](http://php.net/is_numeric) behaviour should be predictable, and I think should work fine here.  I don't see why you need `intval()`.

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ php -r 'if (is_numeric("12er3")) print "yes\n";'
[ghoti@pc ~]$ php -r 'if (is_numeric("123")) print "yes\n";'
yes
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

Once you've confirmed that a variable is_numeric(), you can just use the variable as-is.  PHP is typeless.

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ cat doit.php 
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php

$_GET["uid"]=$argv[1];

if (isset($_GET["uid"]) && is_numeric($_GET["uid"])) {
  $a=preg_split('/[^\d]+/', $_GET["uid"]+0);      # Use only the 
  $id=$a[0];                                      # integer part
  if ($id<0) {
    $id=0;
  }
} else {
  $id=0;
}

print $id . "\n";

[ghoti@pc ~]$ ./doit.php 123
123
[ghoti@pc ~]$ ./doit.php 12er3
0
[ghoti@pc ~]$ ./doit.php ""   
0
[ghoti@pc ~]$ ./doit.php   
0
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

Comment: it fails if input is something like `13.7`.

Comment: So you're saying that non-integer numbers are invalid values for `$id` for you?  That wasn't specified in your question, when I answered it.  Provide more details, and I'll be happy to update my answer.  How do you want numbers like `13.7` treated?  You haven't included instructions for this.

Comment: I added that a few minutes after I posted the question. `$id` is non-negative and integer.

Comment: And how do you want numbers like `13.7` treated?  You haven't included instructions for this.

Comment: And result of `13.7`  should be **13**

Comment: Updated.  Now it uses preg_split() to implement `intval()`.  Why are we avoiding `intval()`, again?

Comment: `intval`  returns first numeric part of its input,e.g input:`12er32` => output => `12`

Comment: That's what preg_split() would do as well, though that doesn't happen here because `is_numeric("12er3")===FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help?

```
if (strval(intval($_GET["uid"])) == $_GET["uid"]) {
    // the value is an integer
}
```

Comment: he specfically said he doesn't want to use intval

Comment: @itachi, not exactly that. he said it behaves funny. i just tried to change it's behavior to useful. :)

Comment: it fails if input is `13e` :-(

Comment: Ops! don't understood why it is not working. However I have updated the script (added `strval` function to it). Now it should work for any input. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
$id = (isset($_GET["uid"]) ? $_GET["uid"] : 0);
if ($id !== strval(intval($id))) {
    $id = 0;
}
$id = max(0, $id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow. I really like [this answer from number 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901738/604259), and am inclined to believe it seems indeed one of the most efficient way to filter out an integer.

IE, reposted for example of the reference, kudos to Martin Geisler for sharing this with us:

```
if (strcspn($_REQUEST['q'], '0123456789') != strlen($_REQUEST['q']))
  echo "true";
else
  echo "false";
```

I would be dying to do benchmarks on this, even if out of just plain curiosity. There are many ways of doing this, and hopefully others may have ideas.

Your first method *looks ok* but I think it may fail in some odd cases. Maybe not, I have not tested your code but I'm thinking if `$_GET['uid']` has a value of `.+1234.56` or some other similar weird cases of the likes you may get unexpected results.

You could easily slap up a couple of tests and a script with the code you you have, each method in their own function, and benchmark this by calling each function 1000 times, you will right away have an idea of the optimal solution 'perfomance-wise'. The result may surprise you. I can assure sure the prettiest code is *not always* the best! I have had to push out some ugly hacks for the sake of performance myself.

As long as your tests are rigourous, and updated as needed (very important) to reflect whatever the requirements of the code  it is testing, you can  use whatever implementation you like *that passes the tests I keep talking about*.

In this case the requirements are quite minimal, it is quite easy to *test*.

Happy coding, cheers!

Comment: @Death Benchmarking is measuring how long code takes to execute, I often use a quick and dirty approch very similar to this: http://www.webdesign.org/web-programming/php/benchmark-and-optimize-php-script-speed.14875.html .  Pear benchmark (http://pear.php.net/package/Benchmark) is also a quick and dirty way to help you with this. There are examples in the documentation on how to use it it is very easy. Keep in mind though, benchmarking is NOT testing. It measures speed of code execution.